# Grid system made footer go too much up to the top of a page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, haml

I created a registration form using twitter bootstrap 3. It look the way I want but the footer is not on its place. How can I make be at the bottom where it should?

[image]

Here is my "layout" (main template):

```
.container
  .row
    != yield
    %hr
    != haml :'shared/_footer'
```

where `!= yield` is place holder for the content of `/registration` page. And here is its content:

```
.col-lg-4.col-lg-offset-4
  .well
    %legend Create your account

    %form{role: :form, action: '/signup', method: :post}
      - if @return_url
        %input{type: :hidden, name: :return_url, value: @return_url}
      .row
        %label.col-xs-4{for: :email} Email
        .col-xs-8
          %input.form-control{id: :email, name: :email, type: :email}
      .row
        %label.col-xs-4{for: :password} Password
        .col-xs-8
          %input.form-control{type: :password, name: :password, id: :password}
      .row
        .col-xs-8.col-lg-offset-4
          %button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block{type: :submit} Create Account
  .clearfix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed adding `<div class="row">` inside of the `.container` before adding your columns. I'd give this a shot first giving you the following code.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-3">
       ...
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<hr>
<footer>
   ...
</footer>
```

**Alternatively**

Since nothing in life is ever easy, it could also be that you have some elements in your form (Position absolute and floated elements) that aren't being counted in the calculation of height on the `div` above the footer.

If this is the case, adding a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` before the closing tag of the main `div` should do it.

**Result should look something like this..**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-3">
   ...
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<footer>
   ...
</footer>
```

Comment: take a look at my update please, I added both clearfix and row, but the result is still the same.

Comment: well, clearfix works only if I place it outside of "<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-3">". However, maybe you know what I can do about the form inputs them-self since they look kind of ugly in terms of layout and size?

Comment: In looking at the updated code, you're missing the `.form-group` wrappers around the label and form field. This is what provides all of the spacing on a Bootstrap form. Try adding `<div class="form-group">...</div>` around each set of labels and form fields.

Comment: I tried different variants, it became looking better but still not really good. Where exactly should I place them: right before input, before .col-xs-8 or before row?

Comment: Generally, this div should be wrapped around the label and input which would make it begin right after the `.row`. You may also try wrapping it only around the input given the way you're attempting to lay out the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this

```
#footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #111;
}
```